# How to get only images using scandir in PHP?

Tags: php, directory-structure, file-extension, scandir, image-file

Is there any way to get only images with extensions `jpeg`, `png`, `gif` etc while using

```
$dir    = '/tmp';
$files1 = scandir($dir);
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can use [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

```
$images = glob('/tmp/*.{jpeg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

If you need this to be case-insensitive, you could use a `DirectoryIterator` in combination with a `RegexIterator` *or* pass the result of `scandir` to `array_map` and use a callback that filters any unwanted extensions. Whether you use `strpos`, `fnmatch` or `pathinfo` to get the extension is up to you.

Comment: That... doesn't use `scandir()` anymore.  But is otherwise correct.  So shouldn't that be "no, with `glob`"?

Comment: Now make it case insensitive. >:)

Comment: @salathe evil hearted you!! :P

Comment: But it doesn't support unicode-charator filename. :(

Answer (score 70):

The actual question was using scandir and the answers end up in glob. There is a huge difference in both where blob considerably heavy. The same filtering can be done with scandir using the following code:

```
$images = preg_grep('~\.(jpeg|jpg|png)$~', scandir($dir_f));
```

I hope this would help somebody.

Comment: This works well, but RegEx should have an 'i' after the ending tilde to make it case-INSensitive, so as to not filter out image / graphic filenames with uppercase extensions like .PNG or .JPG

Answer (score 14):

I would loop through the files and look at their extensions:

```php
$dir = '/tmp';
$dh  = opendir($dir);
while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($dh))) {
    $ext = substr($fileName, strrpos($fileName, '.') + 1);
    if(in_array($ext, array("jpg","jpeg","png","gif")))
        $files1[] = $fileName;
}
closedir($dh);
```

Answer (score 14):

Here is a simple way to get only images. Works with **PHP >= 5.2** version. The collection of extensions are in lowercase, so making the file extension in loop to lowercase make it case insensitive.

```
// image extensions
$extensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp');

// init result
$result = array();

// directory to scan
$directory = new DirectoryIterator('/dir/to/scan/');

// iterate
foreach ($directory as $fileinfo) {
    // must be a file
    if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
        // file extension
        $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($fileinfo->getFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        // check if extension match
        if (in_array($extension, $extensions)) {
            // add to result
            $result[] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
        }
    }
}
// print result
print_r($result);
```

I hope this is useful if you want case insensitive and image only extensions.

Answer (score 9):

You can search the resulting array afterward and discard files not matching your criteria.

`scandir` does not have the functionality you seek.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to scan a directory and return filenames only you can use this:

```
$fileNames = array_map(
    function($filePath) {
        return basename($filePath);
    },
    glob('./includes/*.{php}', GLOB_BRACE)
);
```

`scandir()` will return `.` and `..` as well as the files, so the above code is cleaner if you just need filenames or you would like to do other things with the actual filepaths

Answer (score 1):

I wrote code reusing and putting together parts of the solutions above, in order to make it easier to understand and use:

```
<?php
//put the absolute or relative path to your target directory
$images = scandir("./images");
$output = array();
$filer = '/(.jpg|.png|.jpeg|.gif|.bmp))/';
foreach($images as $image){
  if(preg_match($filter, strtolower($image))){
    $output[] = $image;
  }
}
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: This doesn't work:  `Compilation failed: unmatched closing parenthesis`

Comment: There is one extra parenthesis in the $filter on line 5. Also it's misspelled as $filer. Otherwise seems to work fine!