# Find files with a given extension in a directory tree

Tags: php, filenames

I have a folder in which I have some files and sub-folders. I need to return the names of the files or relative address (if the file is in sub-folder) that have a given extension, for example `.html`.

For example this is structure of given folder:

- /text/something.ncx
- /text/123.html
- content.opf
- toc.ncx
- Flow_0.html
- Flow_1.html
- Flow_2.html

So the code should return this (in an array ideally):

- text/123.html
- Flow_0.html
- Flow_1.html
- Flow_2.html

It's just pulling out names with `.html` extension, but I really don't how to solve this.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062154/php-list-of-specific-files-in-a-directory

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226519/use-php-scandirdir-and-get-only-images

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use a [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/recursivedirectoryiterator) to get *all* files recursively, then filter the result with a [`RegexIterator`](http://php.net/regexiterator) to iterate over only the `*.html` files.  To get the *relative adress*, [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator::getSubPathname()`](http://php.net/recursivedirectoryiterator.getsubpathname) can be used.

```
$directory  = '../path/to/your/folder';
$all_files  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory));
$html_files = new RegexIterator($all_files, '/\.html$/');

foreach($html_files as $file) {
    echo $html_files->getSubPathname(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

If you really need and array (with iterable objects you often don't), you can easily build one up in the `foreach` rather than `echo`-ing each subpath.

Answer (score 2):

To list files from folder (change $directory value to your preffered dirname and @ $files change your extension from .txt to preffered one.

```
$directory = "../images/team/harry/";


$files = glob($directory . "*.txt");


foreach($files as $file)
{
echo $file;
}
```

Comment: This won't recurse into subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [glob function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

```
glob('*.html')
```

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use this

```
<h1>

$Dir = 'you dir/';
$File = scandir($Dir);
$Type = pathinfo($File[$x],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (strtolower($Type) === 'html'){
         echo $File;
}
<H2>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer to the OP, a code dump isn't helpful