# FilesystemIterator only returns one file

Tags: php

Why is this only returning one file?

```
    $iterator = new FilesystemIterator($absoluteDirectoryPath);
    $regexIterator = new RegexIterator($iterator, $filter);
var_dump($regexIterator);
```

I just need a list of files and I can't see anywhere why this would be returning only one file.  Heres the output:

```
RegexIterator {#7 ▼
  +replacement: null
  innerIterator: RecursiveIteratorIterator {#5 ▼
    innerIterator: RecursiveDirectoryIterator {#4 ▼
      path: "/home/**/**/**/**/**/**/**/home"
      filename: "home.php"
      basename: "home.php"
      pathname: "/home/**/**/**/**/**/**/**/**/home.php"
```

I've blanked out the path of course.  But theres only one entry, home.php, when theres at 4 files in this directory.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Comment: @Progman thats really it.  I put a var_dump in there but there is no extra code, I am only getting one entry in the output.

Answer (score 1):

An iterator by definition points to one element. You have to iterate over all elements and store them in a container. You can use [`iterator_to_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php) for this:

```
$iterator = new FilesystemIterator($absoluteDirectoryPath);
$regexIterator = new RegexIterator($iterator, $filter);
var_dump(iterator_to_array($regexIterator));
```

or you can use a `foreach` loop to iterate over all elements and dump each element.

[Here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern) you can read more about iterators.

Comment: Thanks, But why doesnt literally any other example I see show this? They directly have a `foreach` after the RegexIterator and can access the files straight away, which I cant.  See this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9749009/1445985

Comment: @Chud37 The iterator returns the data when you request them via the methods provided by the iterator. You can get the values by using a `foreach` loop as seen in the linked question.

Comment: @Program, yes, But I do that and I get undefined.  I've created a new question because I feel i've worded this one wrong.

Comment: @Chud37 A `foreach` loop uses iterators to iterate over a container. As I wrote in my answer you can use `iterator_to_array`, a `foreach` loop or another way to iterate over the container.