# how to split .PDF files from array in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, arrays, file, codeigniter, directory

There are lot of files in upload folder.
 I used `directory_map();` to list my files in array. I do something like this:

```
$pdf = directory_map('./upLoad/');
pirnt_f($pdf);
```

and the output is like:

```
Array
(
[0] => fonts.css,
[1] => index.html,
[2] => result_pdf_output1.pdf,
[3] => result_pdf_output1.tmp,
[4] => result_pdf_output2.pdf,
[5] => result_pdf_output2.tmp,
[6] => result_pdf_outpu3..pdf,
[7] => result_pdf_output3.tmp,
[8] => result_pdf_output4.pdf,
[9] => result_pdf_output4.tmp,
[10] => result_pdf_output5.pdf,
[11] => result_pdf_output5.tmp,
[12] => result_pdf_output6.pdf,
[13] => result_pdf_output6.tmp,
[14] => result_pdf_output7.pdf,
[15] => result_pdf_output7.tmp,
[16] => result_pdf_output8.pdf,
[17] => result_pdf_output8.tmpf
)
```

but I wanna return `.PDF` files to my view. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$fileNames = array(

    '0' => 'fonts.css', 
    '1' => 'index.html', 
    '2' => 'result_pdf_output1.pdf', 
    '3' => 'result_pdf_output1.tmp', 
    '4' => 'result_pdf_output2.pdf', 
    '5' => 'result_pdf_output2.tmp', 
    '6' => 'result_pdf_outpu3.pdf', 
    '7' => 'result_pdf_outpu3.tmp', 
    );

foreach ($fileNames as $file) {

    $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if ($ext == 'pdf') {
        $pdf[] = $file;
    } else {
        $nonPdf[] = $file;
    }

}

echo "PDF's are";
print_r($pdf);

echo "<br>Non-PDF's are";
print_r($nonPdf);
```

---

**OutPut**

```
PDF's are ==> Array ( [0] => result_pdf_output1.pdf [1] => result_pdf_output2.pdf [2] => result_pdf_outpu3.pdf )     
Non-PDF's are ==> Array ( [0] => fonts.css [1] => index.html [2] => result_pdf_output1.tmp [3] => result_pdf_output2.tmp [4] => result_pdf_outpu3.tmp )
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my Question that I asked.

[How to get only images using scandir in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226519/how-to-get-only-images-using-scandir-in-php)

> You can use `glob`
>
> `$images = glob('/tmp/*.{jpeg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE);` 
>   If you need this
>   to be case-insensitive, you could use a `DirectoryIterator` in
>   combination with a `RegexIterator` or pass the result of `scandir` to
>   array_map and use a callback that filters any unwanted extensions.
>   Whether you use strpos, fnmatch or pathinfo to get the extension is up
>   to you.